# no transaction is in progress - Karaf + Camel 3.3. 0 + JPA

Tags: jpa, apache-camel, spring-data

I have been trying to implement a simple Camel + Karaf Webservice which saves the entity into the database using camel JPA but I haven't been successfully. The problem I am facing is that when I try to save data using to("jpa://entityClass") I am getting the below exception:

```
 javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
            at **org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413) ~[?:?]
    .....
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer$3.doInTransaction(JpaProducer.java:310)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)**
        at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer.processEntity(JpaProducer.java:254)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer.process(JpaProducer.java:173)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:67)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:168)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)...
        at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.doService(CamelContinuationServlet.java:219)
        at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:569)
```

**My Project Setup:**

1. Camel 3.3.0 , Karaf 4.2.10
2. Routes use Java DSL
3. On Karaf, I have installed the MSSQL Data Source which works fine.

**My Camel Context:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-blueprint.xsd"
           >
<bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
   <property name="joinTransaction" value="false"/>
</bean>
   <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="application">
    </cm:property-placeholder>
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"> 
    <package>com.abc.routes</package>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

I see that the Entity Manager and Transaction Manager are getting plugged in correctly and I don't see any issue with respect to DB connectivity:

**Logs**

```
10:01:24.648 INFO [pipe-restart 301] HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiJtaPlatform]
10:01:24.655 INFO [pipe-restart 301] Tracking DataSource for punit camel with filter (&(objectClass=javax.sql.DataSource)(osgi.jndi.service.name=myDs))
10:01:24.658 INFO [pipe-restart 301] Found DataSource for camel osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=myDs)
10:01:24.661 INFO [pipe-restart 301] HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: camel]
10:01:25.037 INFO [pipe-restart 301] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
10:01:24.658 INFO [pipe-restart 301] Found DataSource for camel osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=myDS)
10:01:25.037 INFO [pipe-restart 301] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
10:01:25.127 WARN [pipe-restart 301] HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.mycompany.model
10:01:25.128 WARN [pipe-restart 301] HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.mycompany.model
10:01:25.130 INFO [pipe-restart 301] HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
10:01:26.498 INFO [pipe-restart 301] HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiJtaPlatform]
10:01:26.511 INFO [pipe-restart 301] Persistence units added for bundle camel-db event 128
10:01:26.597 INFO [pipe-restart 301] Blueprint bundle camel-db/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT has been started
10:01:26.600 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Attempting to start CamelContext: camel-2
10:01:26.605 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] JMX is enabled
10:01:26.660 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-2) is starting
**10:01:26.695 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Using EntityManagerFactory found in registry with id [EntityManagerFactory0] org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@33bc3397**
**10:01:26.697 INFO [Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] Using TransactionManager found in registry with id [PlatformTransactionManager0] org.ops4j.pax.transx.tm.impl.geronimo.GeronimoPlatformTransactionManager@3c487367**
```

Can any one help? I have been trying to resolve this for more than a month now. There are solutions for similar problems but not for Camel on Karaf.

Comment: Have you tried to make route transacted? `from("whatever").transacted().to("jpa://entityClass")`. It might be required, since you have set joinTransaction=false explicitly on JPA component.

Comment: Yes,  I did it. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Issue was in the persistence.xml. The transaction-type was set to "RESOURCE_LOCAL" and I changed to JTA and added a JTA data source.